# Can not apply join from unmatched type of field

Tags: php, mongodb

I am learning mongodb join and it works great. It fail to join when we try to join one filed has ObjectId and another field has simple id.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) please look at [ask] and how to create a [mcve]